# Starting my app as administrator while using the <linkedConfiguration> Tag in the app.config file

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I need to use the `<linkedConfiguration>` element in my `app.config`, but at the same time I want to start my app as an administrator, what I could solve with the `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` element in the `app.manifest`.
The result of this is the following error:

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\XYZ.exe".Error in
> manifest or policy file "C:\XYZ.exe.Config" on line 3. The element
> assemblyBinding appears as a child of element configuration which is
> not supported by this version of Windows.

As it's stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/linkedconfiguration-element in the Note, it's not supported:

> The `<linkedConfiguration>` element is not supported for applications
> with Windows side-by-side manifests.

Is there any other way to force my app to start in elevated mode?
(All my search results refer to `app.manifest`)